# Some variables relation for the Turbulent flow

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics

I have the internal area of the pipe(ft^2), flow rate(gpm at 7ft/min), Reynolds number, pressure drop(psi/100ft), and pressure drop(ft/100ft) shown on the flow table as attached. May I know what formulas can be used to connect these variables to see their relations?
Note: because the large Re,it should be  turbulent flow.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [Darcy–Weisbach equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy%E2%80%93Weisbach_equation) with the turbulent  [friction factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy%E2%80%93Weisbach_equation#Turbulent_regime), supplemented by the Moody diagram or Colebrook equation.

[image: Darcy–Weisbach equation]

You can try it with [this online calculator](https://www.tribology-abc.com/calculators/pipeflow_fluid.htm)